# Error when subscribing to a deleted queue

Tags: websocket, queue, rabbitmq, amqp, stomp

I am building a message based web application that supposes to present stocks quotes in real time,

I chose RabbitMQ as my message bus, I have a single exchange that takes streams of quotes from several liquidity providers and route them to the corresponding queues according to the routing key. Then the quote is being parsed and displayed on the relevant widget on the screen.

This is the Exchange and queues structure -

```
| exchange       | type   | routing key       | queue              |
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| quotes         | topic  | NASDAQ.MSFT.500   | Widget1Id          |
| quotes         | topic  | NASDAQ.FB.1500    | Widget2Id          |
| quotes         | topic  | S&P500.ABT.200    | Widget3Id          |
| quotes         | topic  | S&P500.MMM.200    | Widget4Id          |
| quotes         | topic  | S&P500.MMM.500    | Widget5Id          |
```

The queues are Auto-Delete so as soon as I change one of the widgets to another routing key the old queue dies.

But when I want to resubscribe to the old queue I am getting an error.

i.e-

widget1 is subscribed to queue NASDAQ.MSFT.500, now the user want to change the settings and get NASDAQ.FB.1500 so widget1 is unsubscribing from NASDAQ.MSFT.500 and subscribing to NASDAQ.FB.1500.

All good until now,

If widget1 want to subscribe again to NASDAQ.MSFT.500 I am always getting an error:

```
"NOT_FOUND - no queue 'NASDAQ.MSFT.500' in vhost '/'↵"
```

Is that suppose to happened?

Is it not possible to resubscribe to a deleted queue?

Should I not delete queues?

P.S - 
I am using StompJs as my framework for consuming messages from the queues.

Comment: I also experience the same issue when subscribing to a deleted queue. If someone could help in clarifying how should we approach.

Comment: Any RabbitMQ pros?